# getResourceAsStream returns null on win10 if used in gradle plugin task

Tags: java, gradle, gradle-plugin

I need to copy a file from gradle plugin jar to a root of a project that applies the plugin as part of gradle task.

I have a file in gradle plugin jar placed in `src/main/resources/data/file`

I have the following code in gradle task:

```
String filename = "data" + File.separator + "file";
final InputStream stream= classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);
final Path filePath = new File(filename).toPath();
new File("data").mkdirs();
try {
    Files.copy(stream, filePath , StandardCopyOption.REPLACE_EXISTING);
} catch (IOException e) {
    throw new PluginApplicationException("Failed to apply plugin", e);
}
```

I expect this code to take a file from gradle plugin jar and put it into a /data/file.
It works fine on linux when I run the plugin task, but it crashes on windows because `classLoader.getResourceAsStream(fileName);` returns null.

I tried to use different ways to fetch class loader, but it is always VisitableURLClassLoader on both windows and linux. Does anybody have an idea why it is null on windows?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't use `File.separator`. For resources it's always `/`.